# What is a phrase like "in my house" called?

Tags: parts-of-speech, grammatical-roles

What is the grammatical name and function of the clause in bold:

> They were ***in my house*** when the thieves broke in.

Comment: Prepositional phrase

Answer (score 0):

> *They were in my house when the thieves broke in.*

"In my house" is a **preposition phrase** functioning as a locative **complement** of "were".